# How can I search a mailbox with the last checked time, not a date?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

My python code imports imaplib, and goes like:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=server, port=port)
mail.login(account, password)
mail.select()
typ, msgnums = self.mail.search(*WHERE I WANT TO IMPLEMENT*)
```

I connect to the server and check the inbox regularly, and save the last seen mail's time data.

For the next mail check, I want to search the mails that have been received since that time, so that I don't have to handle already-seen mails.

I tried to use one of the SEARCH criteria, but it seems that they only care about a date, not a time.

How can I search emails that have been received since a certain time?

Comment: You should search using UIDs.  On a correctly implemented server, they always increase, so you can just remember the last UID you successfully fetched, and get any UID larger than that.  It’s that simple!

Comment: @Max I considered fetching with UIDs, but isn't a UID changed when some delete operations are done in the mailbox? I did an experiment, and found out that a certain mail's UID is changed after deleting a former email, which I think using UID can not guarantee the accuracy.

Comment: `UID`s don't change from other message being deleted, `MSN`s do (eg, UID SEARCH vs SEARCH and UID FETCH vs FETCH).  They are not the same!  Unless your server is horridly broken, or you are moving messages between folders, UIDs are stable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no search by time in IMAP REF: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4

Anyway you can do it:

```
# get emails that have been received since a certain time
import datetime
from imap_tools import MailBox, A
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(date_gte=datetime.date(2000, 1, 1))):
        print(msg.date.time(), 'ok' if msg.date.hour > 8 else '')
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools